# og:locale fr_BE not recognized

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I'm getting the following error:

> **of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'fr_be' for property 'og:locale:locale' could not be parsed as type 'enum'.**

After looking at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/supported-locales/, I wonder why `fr_BE` is not supported, but `nl_BE` is.

Is there a specific reason, or is this a bug?

Thank you.

Best regards

Comment: There's plenty of other locales that aren't on that list.... are you asking why Facebook doesn't currently support that specific one, or why they don't support all well-known locales in the world?

Comment: I'm asking why it doesn't support, it's an important locale, specially as nl_BE is there. I also should have mentioned what to do in this scenario?

Comment: Use fr_FR instead, I suppose.